# Python Code is working but assert function is not

Tags: python, python-unittest, assert

I am creating a code to convert date format from "dd/mm/yyyy" to "day month year".
the function should delete extra spaces and return ""  if the provided date is erroneous.
The code is working well , but none of the assert function is not working. It keeps giving me errors messages although when I use the function convDate it is working perfectly.

my code is:

```
monthName = ['janvier', 'fevrier', 'mars',        
             'avril','mai', 'juin', 'juillet',
             'aout', 'septembre', 'octobre',
             'novembre', 'decembre']

def month():                                      
    global monthNumber
    monthNumber = []
    for i in range(1, 13):
        if i < 10:
            monthNumber.append("0" + str(i))     
        else:                                   
            monthNumber.append(str(i))
    return monthNumber

def cleaningSpaces():                          
    global splitDate                            
    splitDateSpace = splitDate                  
    splitDate = []
    for i in splitDateSpace:
        if i != "":
            splitDate.append(i)

def checkDateFormat1(date):                    
    global splitDate                          
    if date.find("/") != -1:
        date = date.replace(" ", "")          
        splitDate = date.split("/")
        cleaningSpaces()

        if splitDate[1].isdecimal():
            if len(splitDate[1]) == 1:
                splitDate[1] = "0" + splitDate[1]
                checkDateFormat(date)
        else:
            return ""
    else:
        checkDateFormat2(date)

def checkDateFormat2(date):
    global splitDate
    if date.find("/") == -1:
        splitDate = date.split(" ")
        cleaningSpaces()
        if date.isdecimal():
            return ""
        splitDate[1] = splitDate[1].lower()
        checkDateFormat(date)
    else:
        return ""

def checkDateFormat(date):
    global splitDate
    if True:
        if len(splitDate) != 3:
            return ""
        if len(splitDate[0]) == 1:
            splitDate[0] = "0" + splitDate[0]
        if len(splitDate[2]) != 4:
            return ""
        if splitDate[0].isalpha() | splitDate[2].isalpha():
            return ""
        if int(splitDate[0]) < 1 or int(splitDate[2]) < 1:
            return ""
        getMonthIndex(splitDate)
    else:
        return ""

def getMonthIndex(splitDate):
    global index
    index = -1
    month()
    search_index = False
    while not search_index:
        for i in range(len(monthNumber)):
            if monthNumber[i] == splitDate[1]:
                index = i
                splitDate[1] = monthName[index]
                search_index = True
        break
    while not search_index:
        for i in range(len(monthName)):
            if monthName[i] == splitDate[1]:
                index = i
                splitDate[1] = monthNumber[index]
                search_index = True
        break
    if index == -1:
        return ""
    else:
        validateDate(splitDate)

def validateDate(splitDate):
    indexMonth30 = [3, 5, 8, 10]
    indexMonth31 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11]
    for i in indexMonth30:
        if index == int(i) and int(splitDate[0])>30:
            return ""
    for i in indexMonth31:
        if index == int(i) and int(splitDate[0])>31:
            return ""
    if index == 1 and int(splitDate[0]) > 29:
        return ""
    if index == 1 and int(splitDate[0]) > 28 and int(splitDate[2]) % 4 != 0:
        return ""
    else:
        joinDate(splitDate)

def joinDate(splitDate):
    if splitDate[1].isalpha():
        finalDate = " ".join(splitDate)
    else:
        finalDate= "/".join(splitDate)
    print(finalDate)
    return finalDate

def convDate(date):
    checkDateFormat1(date)

def convDateTest():
    assert convDate("  4 SEptembre 2006     ") == "04/09/2006"
    assert convDate("  4 //9  //  2000     ") == "04 septembre 2000"
    assert convDate("  29  fevrier 2000 ") == "29/02/2000"
    assert convDate("29 /2/ 2021") == ""
    assert convDate("31/4/ 2021") == ""
    assert convDate("-1/4/ 2021") == ""
    assert convDate("31/4/ 4/2021") == ""
    assert convDate("31/4/ 4/20210") == ""
    assert convDate("trois /4/ 4/20210") == ""
    assert convDate("trois /4/2021") == ""
    assert convDate("3 /14 /2021") == ""

convDateTest()
```

I know my code is long and unprofessional , but I am still learning and I like the logic.

Comment: convDate doesn't return anything (same for various other functions)

Comment: `convDate` does not return anything.  Thus, assert will always see `None` and fail.  Even more, however, `checkDataFormat` always returns an empty string, which will also cause the assert to trigger.

Comment: How do you know it is working if the assertions aren't working ? Have you stepped through the code in a debugger and identified any issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you might want to try this

```
def convDate(date):
    return checkDateFormat1(date)
```

So whatever convDate would return be it any kind of string will be evaluated by assert. Also you might want to add return statements to an end logic in a block in other functions and it seems like you will get an empty string returned everytime.